# Real Analysis, Folland Problem 5.3.30 The Baire Category Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

> Problem 5.3.30 - Let $\mathscr{Y} = C([0,1])$ and $\mathscr{X} = C^{1}([0,1])$, both equipped with the uniform norm.
>
> a.) $\mathscr{X}$ is not complete.
>
> b.) The map $(d/dx):\mathscr{X}\rightarrow \mathscr{Y}$ is closed but not bounded.

For a.) I believe since $\mathscr{X}$ is equipped with the uniform norm that is we have $$\lVert C^{1}([0,1])\rVert_{\infty} \neq 0$$ so $\mathscr{X}$ cannot be complete. Not sure if I am defining this correctly, or if that is necessarily true all the time for the interval $[0,1]$.

For b.) I am confused on the mapping here. So I am not sure how to approach the problem.

Any insight or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Notice that $\frac{d}{dx} e^{\lambda x} = \lambda e^{\lambda x}$ and you can take $\lambda$ to be any real number, so $\frac{d}{dx}$ is not bounded.

Comment: I see thanks for the comment are my thoughts on a.) completely off?

Comment: The first part does not indicate incompleteness. See Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map you are supposed to consider is
$$
          \frac{d}{dx} : \mathscr{X}\rightarrow\mathscr{Y}
$$
where $\mathscr{X}$ is $C^1[0,1]$ equipped with the sup norm, and $\mathscr{Y}$ is $C[0,1]$ equipped with the sup norm. To show that $\frac{d}{dx}$ is closed, suppose that $\{ f_n\}\subset\mathscr{X}$ converges to some $f\in\mathscr{X}$, and suppose $\{g_n=\frac{d}{dx}f_n\}\subset\mathscr{Y}$ converges to some $g\in\mathscr{Y}$; you must show that $g=f'$. This follows rather easily from the fact that
$$
                 f_n(t)=f_n(0)+\int_{0}^{t}g_n(t)dt.
$$
Because $\{ f_n \}$ converges uniformly to $f$ and $\{ g_n\}$ converges uniformly to $g$, then
$$
                 f(t) = f(0)+\int_{0}^{t}g(t)dt.
$$
Therefore, $\frac{d}{dx}f = g$. So the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ between these spaces is closed. If $\mathscr{X}$ were a Banach space, then the closed graph theorem would imply that $\frac{d}{dx}$ is bounded, which it is not (see comment from Henry W to your post.) Therefore $\mathscr{X}$ cannot be complete.

Comment: Been absent, I see you proved b.) first and since the closed graph theorem would imply $\frac{d}{dx}$ is bounded which is not the case then $\mathcal{X}$ is not complete?

Comment: @Wolfgang : Yes, that seemed easiest. :)

Comment: Why does $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$ converge uniformly?

Comment: @Wolfy : In showing that the graph of $\frac{d}{dx}$ is closed, you start by assuming $(f_n,g_n=\frac{d}{dx}f_n) \in \mathscr{X} \times\mathscr{Y}$ converges in the graph norm, which means $\{ f_n \}$ converges in the norm of $\mathscr{X}$ (which means uniform convergence because the norm is the uniform norm) and $\{ g_n=\frac{d}{dx}f_n \}$ is assumed to converge in the norm of $\mathscr{Y}$, which is also a uniform norm.

Comment: I see so in the statement of the problem since we are both equipped with a uniform norm and we state that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ then we have uniform convergence essentially?

Comment: @Wolfy : Yes, the nice part of the sup norm is that converge in the sup norm is equivalent to uniform convergence.

Comment: I see, do you know if there is a proof for that floating around somewhere?

Comment: @Wolfy : It's really just the definition of the sup norm: $\|f-f_n\| \le \epsilon$ iff $|f(x)-f_n(x)| \le \epsilon$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: ok thank you for the quick responses

Comment: @Wolfy : You're welcome.